# Mysql request if not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery, union

I need help for a request, maybe it's easy but I didn't succeed to find the way.

I have a table `T` with a lot of rows. One of column `C`, contains an id.
Next to that, I have a listing `L`  of id :

table `T` :

```
- id1
- id2
- id3
```

listing `L` which is not a table, just a listing :

```
id1, id3, id4
```

I want to find in `L`, all ids that not in `T`. Here : id4.

My query:

```
SELECT id FROM T WHERE id IN (id1, id3, id4)
```

allow me to find all id of `L` present in `T`, but I wan't the contrary : all id of `L` **NOT** present in `T`.

Someone has an idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done with a `NOT EXIST` condition and a correlated subquery. This query will give you *all id of L NOT present in T* :

```
SELECT L.id
FROM L
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T WHERE L.id = T.id)
```

If L is a list and not a table, then you could turn it into a table, as follows :

```
SELECT L.id
FROM (SELECT 'id1' id UNION ALL SELECT 'id3' UNION ALL SELECT 'id4') L
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T WHERE L.id = T.id)
```

Comment: L is not a table, it's just a list of ids :/

Comment: @Kozame : where does this list comes from, can we find it in the database ?

Comment: No, we can't find the listing of L in the database. The listing comes from an extern process (e-mail) and I need to find if some ids of this list not exist in db.

Comment: That work, thank you so much ! Not easy with a big list, but that work :D

Comment: Welcome @Kozame ! Please consider upvoting my answer (and The Impaler's too I guess) to indicate the community that it was helpful... Thanks !

Comment: Can't validate 2 answers, but I upvote both. I never find this request by myself, you save my day !

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL **8.x** you can do: if, for example, the list L has three values (123, 456, 789) then you can do:

```
with L as (
  select 123 as id
  union select 456
  union select 789 -- add more values to the list L here
)
select id from L where id not in (select id from T)
```

In MySQL **5.x** you can do:

```
select L.id
from (
  select 123 as id
  union select 456
  union select 789
) L
left join T on L.id = T.id
where T.id is null
```

Comment: L is not a table, it's just a list of ids :/

Comment: That work, thank you so much ! Not easy with a big list, but that work :D